# flask-login: current_user returns None

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I'm currently building a standard app using Flask and flask-login. It is the regular stuff, with Blueprints, Flask-WTF, and whatnot.

The issue I'm having is that current_user returns None when I try to use it in a model that is being called from a class that has the form definition for Flask-WTF.

Here is the model:

```
class Keywords(object):
"""docstring for Tags"""

def taglist(self):
    print('CURRENT_USER in Keywords: ', current_user) <----- None
    ticket = current_user.ticket if current_user else 'test'
    response = TagClient().tags(ticket)
    print(response)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.body['list']['entries']
        return [(entry['entry']['id'], entry['entry']['tag']) for entry in data]
    return []
```

and here is the Flask-WTF form class:

```
class FileForm(FlaskForm):
"""docstring for FileForm"""

print(current_user)

_keywords = Keywords().taglist() <----- THIS DOESN'T WORK
# print('Keywords: ', _keywords)

file                = FileField('File', validators=[FileRequired(), FileAllowed(datasets, 'Datasets only!')])
title               = StringField('Title', validators=[InputRequired()])
shortname           = StringField('Short name', validators=[InputRequired()])
abstract            = TextAreaField('Abstract', validators=[Optional()])
```

However, if I create an instance of the model in the controller it works and current_user returns the user.

```
def upload():
form    = FileForm(formdata=None)
# keywords = Keywords().taglist() <----- THIS WORKS!
# print(keywords)
return render_template('files/upload/wizard.html', user=current_user, title='Upload files', form=form, tree=tree, js=js)
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide.